# Removing specific tags from a string - R

Tags: r, string, tags

I read similar questions and applied them to my case but they did not work. Anyway, How can I remove the `<\/p>\r\n<p>` from an string?
My failed attempts:

```
string <- "Hello!<\/p>\r\n<p>For this skill, I had no idea of what to do at first."
gsub("<\/p>\r\n<p>","",string)
gsub("<\\/p>\\r\\n<p>","",string)
```

Thanks

Comment: @RonakShah, The question is edited

Comment: Do you have a typo? Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Hello!<\/"

Comment: Could you include the `dput` of `string`. As is, `string` throws an error because some of the characters might not be properly escaped.

Comment: Actually, this is the string that I just copied and pasted from the main source. The whole string could not be fitted here.

Comment: Have you tried adding `fixed` to `gsub`? like `gsub("<\\\/p>\r\n<p>","",string, fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following codes

```
string <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", string)
string <- gsub("\\r\\n", "", string,fixed=TRUE)
```